# How can I get BYTE value in JSON string?

Tags: xcode, nsdictionary

I have a problem to get the data from JSON.

I get JSON data from server and change it to NSDictionary, so I can access the value.

Here is the dictionary data.

```
{
"msgData" : [     49     ]
}
```

49 is ASCII code, so I can get '1', but I don't know how can I convert the value into '1'.

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
 short a;
 NSMutableData * data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
 data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"msgData"];
 [data appendBytes:&a length:sizeof(short)];
 [data getBytes:&a];
 NSLog(@"msgData : %d",a);
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
    NSArray *numbersArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"msgData"];
    For (NSNumber *number in numbersArray) {
      NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [number intValue];
      NSLog(@"%@", string);
    }
```